# make average row with the same pattern

Tags: text-processing

I have a huge table (10 columns and 6000 rows) and I have to make an average of all the rows only if they have the same pattern in column 3 (ko).
My table contains numbers and strings.

Here's an example:

```
pvalue  padj    ko  pathway
17,14   0,01    ko00620 Pyruvatemetabolism
15,76   0,01    ko00620 Pyruvatemetabolism
13,22   0,00    ko00620 Pyruvatemetabolism
12,40   0,00    ko00051 Fructoseandmannosemetabolism
12,03   0,01    ko00051 Fructoseandmannosemetabolism
```

I would like to obtain something like this

```
pvalue  padj    ko  pathway
15,38   0,01    ko00620 Pyruvatemetabolism
12,22   0,00    ko00051 Fructoseandmannosemetabolism
```

Comment: You want an average of which column(s)? It looks like your first columns has two fields and you want the average of each of those fields for each knockout. If so, why is the first value 38 and not 37? 14+76+22)/3=37.3. Do you also want the results truncated? Rounded? Do you also want the `padj` column to be treated as two fields and averaged? Please [edit] your question and clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but what the heck, it's fun:

```pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    'dbi:CSV:',
    undef, undef, {
        f_ext           => '.csv/r',
        csv_sep_char    => "\t",
        csv_quote_char  => undef,
        csv_escape_char => undef,
    }
);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
    'SELECT AVG(pvalue), AVG(padj), ko, pathway
    FROM data GROUP BY ko, pathway'
);
$sth->execute();

while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref ) {
    printf "%.2f\t%.2f\t%s\t%s\n", @$row;
}

$dbh->disconnect;
```

The above assumes your data live in tab-separated CSV file named `data.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe GNU's `datamash` is something for you:

```
$ datamash -H -g3,4 mean 1 mean 2 < file
GroupBy(ko) GroupBy(pathway)    mean(pvalue)    mean(padj)
ko00620 Pyruvatemetabolism  15,373333333333 0,0066666666666667
ko00051 Fructoseandmannosemetabolism    12,215  0,005
```

Comment: I'have tried but does not work for my purpose there is something wrong??

Comment: What isn't working? Does `datamash` give an error?

Comment: The script i used is this: datamash -H -g2,1,3,4,23,30,31 mean 5 mean 6 mean 7 mean 8 mean 9 mean 10 mean 11 mean 12 mean 13 mean 14 mean 14 mean 15 mean 16 mean 17 mean 18 mean 19 mean 20 mean 21 mean 22 mean 24 mean 25 mean 26 mean 27 mean 28 mean 29 < vo_ko_count_stat_ko_separati_col1.txt > prova.txt        the reference column is the column 2 and it does not give the average of the column selected

Comment: Well, the file `vo_ko_count_stat_ko_separati_col1.txt` doesn't seem to contains the data you've described in OP and I don't have access to your data, so it's hard to tell where something is wrong.

Comment: the example that i post  it's just an example because i have an huge table how i can send you the table?

Comment: Please add an excerpt (5 rows or something) of your original data to the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23984/discussion-between-ilario-ferrocino-and-flohimself).

Answer (score 0):

with awk

```
awk '
    NR == 1 {print;next} 
    {
        n[$3]++
        val[$3] += $1
        adj[$3] += $2
        path[$3] = $4
    } 
    END {
        for (ko in n) 
            printf "%.2f %.2f %s %s\n", val[ko]/n[ko], adj[ko]/n[ko], ko, path[ko]
    }
' file | column -t
```